# How to insert a note in a cell that has a comment in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

When I go to "Insert note" into a cell that has a comment, the popup for the note either isn't shown, or it's shown briefly and disappears.  The comment seems to be blocking it.

I tried both:

- right-click (on the cell) > Insert note
- Insert > Note

How can I work around this and insert a note?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to workaround this by using the `shift+F2` shortcut for inserting a note.